# Form-based Authentication with a Restful Api in a Java EE Web Application

Tags: ajax, rest, jakarta-ee, architecture, restful-authentication

we have a problem in our web application and I'm looking for some opinions.
The following scenario:

- We have a Java EE Server Application deployed on a JBoss Application Server
- Our Web Application is also deployed in the AS
- The Web Application communicates with the server via JAX-RS
- The Web Application needs authentication

Currently we are using 'form-based authentication', which is directly provided by our Application Server.

The advantage of this approach:

- List item
- We don't have to do anything, but just specify the auth-method 'FORM' and specify a login page
- We can design our login page by ourselves -> the page looks awesome

The disadvantage and also the problem I'd like to discuss:

Our webapplication makes calls (inital-page-load/ajax) to our server application.

If the user is authenticated, it will receive JSON responses. But if the user is not authenticated, the form-based auth will intercept the call and return a html page.
(this looks fishy: WebApp makes a ajax call and expects json, but will receive a http redirect to a html page [login.html]).

The current problem:
At some point the session cookie (of the form-based auth) will timeout, and then the complete application breaks, because each ajax request will not receive any json (as expected), but will receive the login.html page.

Would be really thankful if people who solved that problem could report about their approach and architectural design decisions.

Current Ideas:

- Switch from form-based to something else (and provide a /login rest resource)
- React on the client code on possible wrong responses (if http code 301 -> redirect on login page)
- Something else I can't think of right now